# Yahztee Full House

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to create a simple yahtzee program and am stuck on checking if there is a full house or not.

The count array shown is the array of dice values e.g. count[1]=3 means that there is a 3pair of the 1value. count[3]=2 means there is a 2pair of the 3value die.

```
/**
 * If the category is not yet taken, scoreFullHouse
 * makes sure there are two of one kind and three
 * of another.  If there are, it puts a score
 * of 25 into the HOUSE category, marks the category as taken,
 * and adds 25 to the total score.
 *
 * @param count is the count array of all dice values
 */
private void scoreFullHouse(int[] count)
{
    if (!taken[Category.HOUSE.ordinal()]) //Checks if the house category is taken.
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; ++i)
        {
          if (count[i]=2 || count[i]=3)
          {
            if (count[i+1]=3)
            {
                scores[Category.HOUSE.ordinal()] = HOUSE_VALUE; //Makes the HOUSE_VALUE(25) the score
                taken[Category.HOUSE.ordinal()] = true; //Sets category to taken
                total = total + HOUSE_VALUE;  //Adds the total
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I know this isnt right but it has the basic backbone of what I am trying to do. What I cant figure out is how to check the array to see if there is a 2pair and a 3pair present at the same time. A full house is 3 of one dice 2 of another

Would doing this work?

```
if (count[i]=2 || count[i]=3)
{
  if (count[i+1]=3 && count[i]!=3 || count[i+1]=2 && count[i]!=2)
  {
```

Comment: what is a -Yahztee Full House ?

Comment: @james: Three dice of one value, two of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this.

```
int six = 6;
int values[] = new int[six+1]; // waste a byte so it indexes right
for(int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
    values[dice[i]]++;  // keep counts
}

// now do...
boolean hasAThree = false;
boolean hasATwo = false;

for(int i = 1; i <= six; i++) {
    if(values[i] == 3) {
        hasAThree = true;
    }
    if(values[i] == 2) {
        hasATwo = true;
    }
}

if(hasAThree && hasATwo) {
    // full house
}
```

Comment: Your very first line wants to be `new int[7]` since the argument is the length of the array and, as you mentioned, we waste one byte (index `0`). `(new int[6])[6]` will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. And there is a bug in the bounds of the `for` as well.

Comment: @AlexR there's only 5 dice in yahtzee.

Comment: Yes but each of them is still six-sided. `dice.length == 5` but `values.length == 6 + 1` (wasted index)

Comment: Still the for loop is erroneous. It won't find any sixes.

Comment: Usual for loops in my code look like `for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)` so I don't have to worry :D Also note that `values[0] == 0` anyways so you don't even have to start at `1` to still be correct.

Comment: @AlexR this is a little different though. I'm not using the array as an array; I'm using it as a map where the indices are integer keys. In production code I would never do this for this reason - it *should* be a map for clarity's sake. I figured OP would want a more elementary solution though.

Comment: Of course; and if using arrays there in production code (wich is still legitimate due to the simplicity), I wouldn't waste a int there but instead use `values[dice[i]-1]` as assignment target.

Answer (score 0):

**A few things to note:**

First, "count[i] = n" is assigning the value of "n" to variable in "count" at index "i". On the other hand, "count[i] == n" evaluates the Boolean value of whether "count[i]" and "n" are the same value. Therefore, your if statements should look like this:

```
if(count[i] == 3){
    // do something
}
```

This second point isn't addressing out anything wrong syntactically, but in Java (and many other languages), standard convention has you start with zero, in part because arrays and similar data structures count the first value they contain as being index "0", the second as index "1", and so on. This has the added bonus of being able to have the condition as being less than the length of an array you with to loop through. As it currently stands, your loop never checks the first value in your array, starting with index "1", and would throw an error when you tried to access the value at index "6" (assuming count has a length of six, one index for each dice face). Here's an example of a pretty standard for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
    // do something
}
```

(note also that i++ is much more commonly used than ++i, even though they are identical in this situation)

**Actual answer:**

As for an easy way to identify a full house, keep in mind there are only five dice total, so a full house will have only twos and threes of a kind. This fact, along with the fact that you cannot add up to five dice with only sets of two or sets of three, means that you can just check to make sure there is no dice value that occurs an number of times other than two or three:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    if(count[i] != 2 && count[i] != 3){
        // any "count" which enters this body is not a full house.
        return;
    }
}
// any "count" that continues through the method beyond the loop will be a full house.
```

As far as I can tell the actual scoring part looks fine, though I can't say for 100% certain only seeing this one part.

Comment: loop is wrong since zero is legal, and code that detects certain things that might be a solution isn't actually useful at all.

Comment: Half the point of this post was to stop bad coding practices before they became habits. There is no reason to have the zero index represent anything other than the number of times a one appears in the roll. I would be curious to hear any possible case which would either necessitate having some other value in zero, or in which the sample code I wrote identified anything that was not a full house as a full house (or vise versa).